# Zap proxy connection issue behind corporate proxy

Tags: zap

I'm trying to use the zap proxy running on docker image. It works good on my local machine but when trying to use it behind corporate network the zap proxy requests timeout because it can't connect to the internet. I already have configured the http_proxy and https_proxy environmental variables but it seems that zap proxy isn't using them

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a chained proxy (outbound proxy) for ZAP to use. Via Tools : Options > Connection (in the GUI), or the endpoints below in the API.

- optionUseProxyChain
- optionUseProxyChainAuth
- optionProxyChainName
- optionProxyChainPassword
- optionProxyChainPort
- optionProxyChainPrompt
- optionProxyChainRealm
- optionProxyChainSkipName
- optionProxyChainUsername
- proxyChainExcludeDomains

Comment: I'm using it on Linux server so I don't have GUI. Is there configuration files where I can do those edits or even to the Java code of the Zap or in the python API.

Comment: You can use the endpoints above in python, methods are named with underscores I believe. You could also use ZAP on a desktop or whatever to setup the config and copy the config file.